# spark addJar from hdfs in a jupyter python notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, dependencies, hdfs

We are running a jupyter notebook connected to a hdfs & spark cluster. Some user need to use a jar lib for a use case that we don't want to deploy for all notebooks. So we don't want to add this dependency to the global deployment of our solution.

We are looking for a way for spark to load the jar lib from hdfs, that is accessible by all nodes and edge nodes of our cluster. And we tried to use addJar to load it in the notebook that requires it, but to no avail. We tried:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
      .config("spark.jars", "hdfs:///some/path/the-lib_2.11-0.13.7.jar") \
      .appName('test jar imports - .config(spark.jars)') \
      .getOrCreate()
```

and

```
spark.sparkContext._jsc.addJar("hdfs:///some/path/the-lib_2.11-0.13.7.jar")
# note that print(spark.sparkContext._jsc.sc().listJars()) does contain the above path
```

My intuition is that addJar doesn't work with hdfs, but I don't know really

=> My question: Is there a way to load a jar lib from hdfs into a python spark notebook programatically (that is not a hack, see below)?

---

Also we found a hack that works, by changing the spark-submit args. But we are not satisfied by it because it works thanks to a replace on the expected current args:

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'].replace(', pyspark-shell',',hdfs:/some/path/the-lib_2.11-0.13.7.jar pyspark-shell')
spark = SparkSession.builder \
      .appName('test jar imports os.environ --jars') \
      .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: See if [SparkFiles](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkFiles.html) work for you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
hdfs_path = "hdfs:///some/path/the-lib_2.11-0.13.7.jar"
sc = spark.sparkContext
sc.addFile(hdfs_path)
```

The addFile method of the SparkContext object can be used to add a file to the distributed cache of Spark.

Then it will be available on all the worker nodes.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("myapp").set("spark.jars", hdfs_path)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Comment: I will test it, tx. One question though: you need a sparkContext to addFile, and then create a new one to add the jar. So there must be 2 context ?

Comment: oh no sorry!, it was my mistake! only one spark context at a time can exist in a spark application